# SQL Duplicate Row Results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very simple select query which is being used to create an input file for a piece of software. I have the query pulling all the required fields, however I need to replicate the results six times with a hard coded ID number (1,2,3,4,5,6).

I have seen CROSS APPLY and PIVOT but the problem is the column I need to use for these doesn't exist as I'm hard coded then number.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Apologies the query was so simple I didn't think I needed to add it but as requested: SELECT 1 AS ID,
  [Reference],
  [Name],
  [Business Type]
  
FROM Quarterly_Download

Comment: I asked because there are different ways depending on whether it is an aggregate query or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
select CJ.ID,T.* from dbo.Table T
        CROSS JOIN
        (select 1 ID UNION ALL select 2 ID UNION ALL select 3 ID UNION ALL select 4 ID UNION ALL select 5 ID UNION ALL select 6 ID) CJ
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a pure guess here, but are you saying that every row in your table needs to be repeated 6 times with the ID 1-6? If so, you can use a CTE of the values 1-6 and CROSS APPLY to that.

```
WITH Nums AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) V(N))
SELECT *
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY Nums;
```